# Centering a Submenu (Child Menu, Hover Menu)

Tags: wordpress

Please refer to my project: http://www.lightertaste.com/

If you look at the main navigation (after Browse the Recipes), each menu item has a submenu, but I can't seem to get them completely centered to their parent menu.

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
/*
Site Navigation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.genesis-nav-menu:before {
 margin-right: 10px;
 content: "BROWSE THE RECIPES:";

 font-family: 'arquitecta-black';
 color: #f15c58;
 font-size: 13px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu {
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
 border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
 padding: 10px 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

nav.nav-primary div.wrap {
 border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
 padding: 2px 0px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
 display: inline-block;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 9px;
 padding-right: 12px;

 font-family: 'arquitecta-medium';
 color: #4a4947;
 font-size: 13px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu-item:last-child a {
 padding-right: 0px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover {
 color: #f15c58;
}

li#menu-item-281, li#menu-item-119, li#menu-item-120, li#menu-item-121, li#menu-item-124 {
 padding-right: 4px;
}

li#menu-item-281:after, li#menu-item-119:after, li#menu-item-120:after, li#menu-item-121:after, li#menu-item-124:after {
 display: inline-block;
 content: "/";
 color: #b1b1b1;
}

/* Sub Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.menu-primary li {
 position: relative;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu  {
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
 z-index: 2000;
 width: 200px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #4a4947;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #4a4947;

 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 11px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #f15c58;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="screen-reader-text">Main navigation</h2><nav class="nav-primary" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="genesis-nav-primary" aria-label="Main navigation"><div class="wrap"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary"><li id="menu-item-281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-281"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Appetizers &#038; Snacks</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-297" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-297"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dips &#038; Spreads</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-389" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-389"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Meat &#038; Fish</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-390" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-390"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Fruits &#038; Vegetables</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-119"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breakfast</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-299"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Eggs &#038; Omelettes</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pancakes &#038; Waffles</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-260"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Oatmeal &#038; Granola</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-259"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads, Muffins, &#038; Pastries</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-261"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Shakes &#038; Smoothies</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Lunch</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-258"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sandwiches &#038; Wraps</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-262" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-262"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Salads &#038; Power Bowls</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-263"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Soups &#038; Stews</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-121"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dinner</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-279" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-279"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Quick &#038; Easy</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-278"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Beef &#038; Pork</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-276"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Chicken &#038; Poultry</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-277"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Seafood &#038; Shellfish</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-273"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Casseroles &#038; One-Pans</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-274" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-274"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pastas &#038; Risottos</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pizzas &#038; Flatbreads</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-124"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Desserts</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-264"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cakes &#038; Pies</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cookies &#038; Brownies</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-288"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Ice Creams &#038; Sorbets</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-123"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sides</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-392" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-392"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Vegetables &#038; Potatoes</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-391" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-391"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Rice &#038; Noodles</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads &#038; Rolls</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You submenu is actually correctly centered, but it looks like it isn't because of the separators: / menu /
If you take into account the padding around the menu, and that all your menus are 200px wide, you can use :

```
 .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu  {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -110px;
    /* instead of
    transform: translateX(-50%); */
}
```

But douse margin-left: 100px on the first and the last elements:

To do this, add a new rule with the following selector:

```
 .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu:first-child,
    .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu:last-child,
    .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu:first-child,
    .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu:last-child,
    .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu:first-childfor,
    .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu:last-child {
         left: 50%;
         margin-left: -100px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but how should I add to the first and last?

Comment: Seems I can only get it to work if I remove the separators.

Comment: using vertical separators will also fix your problem.